# john papa's style upgrade to 1.6.2 issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using John Papa's style, here is my component:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myModule')
    .component('myComponent', myComponent());

function myComponent() {
    var component = {
        bindings: {
            dateOptions: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'myComponent.component.html',
        controller: MyController
    };
    return component;
}


function MyController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.getData = getData;

    vm.$onInit = function() {

    };

    function getDate() {
        var options = {
            config: vm.dateOptions.config
        };
    }

}
})();
```

here is the html:

```
<div  class="datearea" ng-click="$ctrl.getDate()">

</div>
```

when I fire the ng-click, it says:

Cannot read property 'config' of undefined

which is the line : config: vm.dateOptions.config

Really interest to know what caused this issue? 
And I would not use the temp fix: 
`$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);`

(This component is working on 1.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out that nothing wrong with this style...
Because the parent passing the null data....